# ways to increase the page loading performance

Tags: jquery, asp.net, performance-testing

What are the ways to increase the page loading performance:
like loading initial contents and show the page
then recheck the database and get rest of the detail and add to the page

Comment: depends on what is causing the slowdown, if you know that then you should be better able to optimize.

Comment: I guess few tools can definitely help you to know what is causing the problem such as YSlow and Firebug.

Answer (score 4):

Some rules that are there to improve upon the page load are as follows:-

1. Use Sprites instead of multiple images.
2. Try putting the JavaScript at the end of the page.
3. Use a Content Delivery Network for transacting static files.
4. Use Ajax so that the entire page does not have to travel across the server rather just the information required refreshes.
5. Use gzip to zip the images and other downloadable static content.
6. Reduce the number of HTTP request.

A much informative description can be found in this link http://www.die.net/musings/page_load_time/

You can also tey out [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) and [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) for this perpose.

Answer (score 0):

These are the links that you may find it useful

[Asp.Net performance and scalablity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647787.aspx) ,
[Jquery & Asp.Net](http://www.datasprings.com/resources/articles-information/jquery-and-asp.net-for-high-performance-ajax)